# Installation of neo4j on ubuntu 14.04 fails

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to install neo4j in ubuntu 14.04 as specified in http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/?_ga=2.249168388.2041192375.1507250087-893468657.1507250087

The installation instruction I am using is

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j=3.2.3
```

but it doesn't work

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package neo4j
```

I'd apreciate any help

Comment: And you also added the repository as specified just before that ? Just checking :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add the debian repository and to update your list of packages:

```
wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo 'deb https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
sudo apt-get update
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/#debian-add-repository

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Debian and installing "apt-transport-https" fixed it because `deb https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/` is using https.
You can install it with this:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```